# wrong calculation of discount product

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have a problem when calculate percentage of discount from old price to new price. when old price more than $100 the percentage of discount value is wrong, but when below than $100 the percentage of discount is correct. what wrong with this script? really need your help guys..
I use magento 1.4,

```
$_oldprice= substr(Mage::helper('core')->currency($_regularPrice,true,false),2);
$_newprice= substr(Mage::helper('core')->currency($_finalPrice,true,false),2);
$_discountprice= $_oldprice- $_newprice;
$count1 = $_discountprice / $_oldprice;
$count2 = $count1 * 100;
$count = number_format($count2, 0);
```

[image: printscreen of the error discount]

Comment: somebody help me please..

Comment: again, somebody help me please..

Answer (score 0):

$discountPercentage= (($_oldprice- $_newprice)/$_oldprice )*100;

this is the formula that should be used.

Comment: ((120-110)/120 ) *100  will be 8.33% which is correct.Make sure your brackets are placed as per mathematical priorty.  Here 120 is old price and 110 is new price.

Comment: if still KO give us an example please

Comment: Provide with what value is being displayed and what were the previous and New cost.Its more of mathematics so as to look in.

Comment: ((1027400-821920)/1027400 ) * 100 = 20  so not sure why you are getting 82%